# AngularJS Directive Passing Unknown Number Of Functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I understand that when writing an AngularJS directive that you can bind a function in the parent scope to the directive scope by using "&" in the directive scope like so:

```
...
scope: {
    functionNameInDirectiveScope: '&attributeName'
}
...
```

As part of a larger directive, what I am wanting to do is pass an unknown number of functions defined on the parent scope to a directive, as the functions to execute on ng-click of a button. For example using this HTML

```
...
<myDirective button1="function1" button2="function2" ... />
...
```

And have the output of the directive to be something like

```
...
<button ng-click="function1()" />
<button ng-click="function2()" />
...
```

Where clicking the buttons will actually run the parent scope functions.

I have figured out how to loop through the attributes and get the names of the functions, I just need to be able to get them bound to the ng-click attributes of the buttons.

It seems like what I want is to be able to manually, in the link function of the directive, be able to do the function binding that the "&" does in the scope part of a directive definition.

I hope this makes sense. Please ask if I didn't explain anything well enough, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a directive ?

Just do it plainly:

```
<button ng-repeat="functionPointer in functionPointers" ng-click="functionPointer" />
```

I haven't tried it myself but it looks like it could work.

Comment: I will edit the question to be more clear ... this is actually part of a larger directive that the buttons are being created in.

Comment: It will at least have to be `ng-click="functionPointer()"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty way of doing what you've asked for following the approach you suggested:

```
directive('myDirective', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      angular.forEach(attrs.$attr, function(func){
        var el = '<button ng-click="' + attrs[func] + '">' + func + '</button>';
        var compiled = $compile(el)(scope);
        elem.append(compiled);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7CnQclSuOlw04nE9ilKk?p=preview)

... but I have doubts about whether it's the best approach for accomplishing your ultimate goals because it gets away from the declarative nature of Angular apps.

If that's something you'd like to address, perhaps you can either update your question or open a new one with more detail about the larger directive.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "it gets away from the declarative nature of angular apps"? Do you mean because this solution is creating the HTML hard-coded in the directive?

Comment: Yes, exactly -- what should be declarative (apparent in the view) is imperative (hidden in the `link` function)

Comment: My plan is actually to have the template where the <button> tag is located loaded by the directive and the buttons added using an ng-repeat. It all works, except hooking up the button action functions.